# How can I get R to stop autocompleting my quotes/parens?

Tags: r

When I type a left paren or any quote in the R console, it automatically creates a matching one to the right of my cursor. I guess the idea is that I can just type the expression I want inside without having to worry about matching, but I find it annoying, and would rather just type it myself. How can I disable this feature?

I am using R 2.8.0 on OSX 10.5.8.

Comment: I agree. I think R programming question would be a better fit on StackOverlfow.com than here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

Comment: @mbq: @JohnD.Cook: This is not a programming question. It is also not a question about a common tool of programmers. It is a question about a common tool of statisticians. That is why I asked it here. I don't mind that it was closed, though, since I received and accepted the correct answer.

Comment: It is a question about using a computer program use; so I think you should try SuperUser. Dirk is there, so R questions will be answered in a blink of eye ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On OSX, go to `R > Preferences > Editor` and deselect `Match braces/quotes`

Answer (score 4):

To follow on from Dirk's comment, if you don't like your current IDE, check out some of the existing discussion on R IDEs:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439059/best-ide-texteditor-for-r

Answer (score 3):

Well either use a different IDE -- this is entirely a feature of the OS X app -- or try to configure the feature in question.

As for IDEs / R environments, I'm rather happy with [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org)  which works on every platform R works on.